# What was from the jungle in "jack ate apple on the table from the jungle", the apple or the table?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> Jack ate apple on the table from the jungle.

Does the sentence mean that apple was from the jungle or the table was from the jungle?

Comment: This sentence (corrected to ... the apple ...) is crying out for expansion. << Jack ate the apple he found on the table; it had come that day from the jungle. >> OR << Jack ate the apple he found on the table: the table had been made by First Nations villagers in the jungle. >> Being ungrammatical isn't the only way a sentence can be unacceptable.

Comment: The answer is, "This is a garbage sentence. It's vague and so there's no way to know what thing is from the jungle."

Comment: Welcome! Can you tell more about where you found this sentence, and the context around it? As you can see, we have no way of knowing for sure.

Comment: Note, people are talking about adding "the" to apple because it's what we call a [count noun](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/nouns). You wouldn't need it for "Jack ate oatmeal on the table."

Comment: This is an "apple" sentence.  You probalby have a real question of grammar.  There is something that you want to express.  Unfortunately you have chosen to hide your real question and ask an apple sentence.  An apple sentence is a sentence about apples that has been created to illustrate some point of grammar.  In this case, the apple sentence is badly formed, so it is almost meaningless.  In real English, much of the meaning comes from context.  By changing your real problem to an apple sentence you remove all the context. The result is a sentence that is unidiomatic and ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence should be:
Jack ate **the** apple on the table from the jungle.

and it means either

1. Jack was on {the table that came from the jungle} when he ate the apple.
2. Jack ate the apple that was on the table. That table came from the jungle

Comment: it could also mean jack ate the apple that was on the table while he was in the jungle, but not likely for sure.

Comment: @EliHarold No it could not.

Comment: @DJClayworth yes it could, in the same way that "I could open the mail box that is in the ground from my car." "jack could eat an apple on the table from the jungle."

Comment: imagine jack is in the jungle and there is a table just outside of the jungle with an apple on it. jack could go out of the jungle to eat the apple or jack could eat the apple on the table FROM the jungle. in the second case he would be reaching his head to eat the apple while still in the jungle versus walking fully out of the jungle to eat the apple.

Comment: As I said, that is unlikely but technically possible. If "the jungle" is used metaphorically this is even more likely. If someone is in a super busy work environment you could say they are "in the jungle." So it would make since then to say "she called her kids, who were at home, from the jungle."

Comment: In all of these examples "from the jungle" is referring to the location of the subject while taking the action.

Comment: I'd argue that @EliHarold's suggestion, while technically valid, strains credulity. But as long as we're pointing out wacky interpretations, the sentence makes it quite possible that Jack himself hopped up onto the table to eat the apple! Perhaps Jack was also from the jungle. Come to think of it, nobody said he's human...

Comment: Agree Andy, and that was kinda my point.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is unacceptable.

In a real sentence we would use the context to understand what is "on the table" and what is "from the jungle".  But in your sentence, divorced from context or reality, the result is ambiguity.

Such ambiguity doesn't occur in real English.